# sql mysql query for fetching a defined numbers of rows randomly based on condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I am developing a Online Exam Application where I have a question master table which contains a field ( name : qtype ) containing the data for the type of question. A question type can be either of following three types :

1. single
2. multiple
3. desc

The application is generating a random question paper from this master table by using the following query :

```
select * from mst_question where test_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
```

This generates a random questionnaire of 25 questions for my Online Exam Application.

So far Its working good...

Now, I need to implement a feature in my application where the 25 randomly generated questions ( or whatever number  - this will depend on the test id ) will always have a FIXED mix of the different types of questions available in the master question table ( mst_question  ) for every randomly generated questionnaire set.

Say, if master question table is having 108 questions for a particular test id and all the three types of questions are in the db for this test , it will provide same number of different types questions for each random query !! I have written the following sql query to find out the percentage of each type of question in the master question table.

So far i have tried this and came up with this sql query :

```
select qtype,count(*) as qtypetotal,(select count(*) from mst_question where test_id = 1) as totalqtype,round((count(*)/(select count(*) from mst_question where test_id = 1)*100),2) as qtypepercentage from mst_question where test_id = 1 group by qtype
```

The output of above query is :

```
qtype       qtypetotal  totalqtype  qtypepercentage  
desc        24      108     22.22 %  
multiple    34      108     31.48 %  
single      50      108     46.30 %
```

I need to form a sql query which will give me 25 randomly generated questions where 22.22% of 25 questions should be desc type , 31.48 % of 25 questions should be multiple type and remaining 46.30 % of 25 questions should be single type.

I am stuck ....... Pls advise...

Thanks in advance :-)

Thanks @MikeBrant.... I have generated the dynamic sql which is definitely the way i wanted... just one issue now.... if i execute this sql query :

```
select qtype,round(25*(count(*)/(select count(*) from mst_question where test_id = 1))) as numquests from mst_question where test_id = 1 group by qtype
```

I am getting the following results :

"desc"          "6"
"multiple"  "8"
"single"    "12"

and based on the above query i generate this dynamic query :

```
$dynamicsql[] =  "(SELECT * FROM mst_question WHERE test_id = 1 AND qtype = '".trim($rstype->qtype)."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$rstype->numquests.")";

$finalsql = implode(" UNION ALL ",$dynamicsql)." ORDER BY RAND()";
```

I want to generate a total of 25 random questions but the sum of these qtypes is 26 !!! and i am getting a question extra :-(

Comment: Try thinking about it this way - you need 24 random questions of type `desc` for every test...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably just use a UNION here:

```
    (SELECT * FROM mst_question
    WHERE test_id = 1 AND qtype = 'desc'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT X)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM mst_question
    WHERE test_id = 1 AND qtype = 'multiple'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT Y)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM mst_question
    WHERE test_id = 1 AND qtype = 'single'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT Z)
ORDER BY RAND()
```

You can use a query like you posed on your original question to get the values for X, Y, and Z to be used.

Comment: Error Code : 1221
Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
(0 ms taken)

Comment: @Sandy505 Ah yes.  how silly of me.  Would actually need to use subselects to make this happen. See updated answer.

Comment: @sgeddes I wasn't intending for those to be actual variables but rather placeholders for values that would be determined by a prior query which would determine the proper mix of questions.

Comment: @MikeBrant: You don't need all the nested tables. It can be simplified.

Comment: @ypercube Would be interested in how you would propose to do this.  The intent here was to grab X-Y-Z number of random questions and then randomize the overall order of the questions.

Comment: Edited. It's just a syntax difference (that MySQL allows.) No change in your logic.

Comment: This query wont work as desired because if my previous query returns only two types of question types or if one type , the calculation will go wrong !!! I need to take percentage from my previous query and pass on to a new query based on the results of previous query ( i guess some "case" statment would help !! )

Comment: @Sandy505 You could dynamically build your query based on the results of your first query, making as many UNIONS as needed to join all the question types and substituting the appropriate qtypes and limit values into the query.